# Executing a WMIC command line argument in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, interface, cmd, wmic

I'm trying to use the WMIC command 'DESKTOP' in an application through a method which is implemented from an interface. Before using WMIC commands in cmd, it's necessary to first input 'WMIC' and press enter, as I'm sure you all know. I can do this just fine, however after the command line enters WMIC mode, I need to subsequently enter the DESKTOP command, or any other WMIC command (see list : http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html). Here's the overridden method code I'm currently using to enter WMIC mode :

@Override
    public void Desktop(){

```
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String cmd = "cmd /c WMIC";

        Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);

}
```

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the output stream of the process you started and write to it.

```
OutputStream os = pr.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
bw.write("DESKTOP");
bw.newLine();
bw.flush();
```

If you need to see the output/errors from the process you started you need to use getInputStream() and getErrorStream() methods to get the output/error streams and read from it.

Check the javadoc of Process for more details.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Pay special attention to this part -

> By default, the created subprocess does not have its own terminal or
>   console. All its standard I/O (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations
>   will be redirected to the parent process, where they can be accessed
>   via the streams obtained using the methods getOutputStream(),
>   getInputStream(), and getErrorStream(). The parent process uses these
>   streams to feed input to and get output from the subprocess. Because
>   some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard
>   input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream
>   or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess
>   to block, or even deadlock.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful comment. I tried adding the above code to the method along with a buffered reader to display output & managed to correctly run the WMIC command 'SOUNDDEV'. It should work with other commands too :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly silly answer.

WMIC is normally used in non interactive mode.

```
wmic desktop get
```

However you are a programmer. Therefore you are supposed to program.

Here's vbs script that does it. The help is filled with sample scripts in C, VB, VBS, and JScript.

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Desktop")

For Each objItem in colItems
    msgbox objItem.Name & " " & objItem.Wallpaper
Next
```